# Scroll to the ExpandableListView in full screen

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-xml

Hello everyone :) I use the ExpandableListView. My ExpandableList is in a portion of the screen. I was expecting the results is **when the list is expanded, than increase the size of the entire screen**. But my list also has a own scroll. (wrap_content, match_parent, Ndp are all the own scroll.) Please refer to the picture.

[image]

Can you see scroll bar in ExpandableList? **I want to be Expandable List scrolls the entire screen.**

My xml code (Unnecessary parts in question was removed) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <ExpandableListView
                    android:id="@+id/pastMedalList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:groupIndicator="@null"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ooh not a good idea to have `ListView` in a `ScrollView` like this, it will cause UI performance issues. Also, its not easy to scroll the whole screen once you reach the list.

Comment: May i also suggest taking what you have above your ListView and adding it via `addHeaderView(View v) ` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)

Comment: @inner_class7 That xml source was being used as a FrameLayout in Fragment. So I put FrameLayout in the ScrollLayout. And I'll try as you help! Really thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it self. I add this method in Activity.

```
private void setExpandableListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView, int group) {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, view, listView);
        if (i == 0) {
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        if(((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group)) || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
            View listItem = null;
            for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, listItem, listView);
                listItem.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                listItem.measure(
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
        }
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

And used as follows :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable, container, false);

    ExpandableAdapter adapter = new ExpandableAdapter();
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    setExpandableListViewHeight(expandableListView, -1);
    expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            setExpandableListViewHeight(parent, position);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```